# auto translate website content when page load using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want a solution for auto translation of data coming from database. 
Details:

1. I am developing a website in multiple language(french & english) using codeigniter.
2. I have a multiple domain(e.g. for french->domainname.fr and for english domainname.uk).
3. I have two files folder for each website in ftp but database is same i mean one.
4. The language of file folder for each website is only in english.

**Requirements:**

1. what to do for auto translate the language of website content.
   ex. website content will be in french when domainname.fr is loaded, and
   english when domainname.uk website is loaded.
2. I dont want to click on any translate button to translate the website content. it will be auto when website load.
3. How to auto translate of data coming from database according to domainname.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multilingual set up of codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771112/multilingual-set-up-of-codeigniter)

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939931/how-to-create-codeigniter-language-files-from-database
You can get help from this.

Comment: sorry, but my issue is not solved. actually my issue is the data coming from the database to webpage would be auto translate according to websites language.i mean to say i have three domain but database is one for all these three, therefore all users's form french, italy, and english will be enter there comment, data in there languageand it will be enterd in same database. Now i want when all data from the database shown in the website will be according to domain language.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called internationalization or i18n.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Here's there wiki about using the language class:
https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations